# Alignment in the QFormLayout on Mac

Tags: macos, qt

I need to create form. In the left side should be checkbox, in the right - line editor.

```
formLayout->addRow( new QCheckBox( "test 1" ), new QLineEdit );
formLayout->addRow( new QCheckBox( "test 1111111" ), new QLineEdit );
```

On mac CheckBox aligned to the center of the form. To set left alignment I tried to use:

```
formLayout->setFormAlignment( Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop );
```

But the CheckBox stays aligned to center.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Try `QFormLayout::setLabelAlignment` ("label" here means 1st column).

Comment: Hm... yes it works. I can swear, that I tried this function earlier but it did not help... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `QFormLayout::setLabelAlignment` to set alignment of form labels (i.e. items in the first column).